How to let buffer show relative path when splitting?
It seems to be a vanilla-vim issue as the same behaviour also appears when I'm in vim -u NONE.
Basically if you open a file, for example vim src/vector.h, and then split it with :bel vsp %:p:h/vector.cpp, the new split buffer will show the name with its full path. Only if I run :cd %:p:h/../ will the buffer display relative path.
How do I fix this behaviour so that it shows relative path correctly? Since I can't just use autocmd to do the :cd thing on bufopen, as not all files' directory are on the same level, so the command might need to be like :cd %:p:h/../../.

Do you mean :vsp[lit]? I’m not aware of an Ex command :vip

Totally unrelated to the issue, but vector.h, seriously? This is just asking for confusion with the standard library's vector.

You get the full path because you give the full path to Vim. Use a relative path instead.

When you do:
:vsplit %:p:h/foo.bar

Vim expands %:p:h to the full path of the directory containing the current file. This means that you give Vim the full path of foo.bar, which becomes the name of the associated buffer. In other words, you get exactly what you asked for.
If you prefer your buffers to be named after their relative path, then… use a relative path:
:vsplit %:h/foo.bar

See :help filename-modifiers.
